# Why is python printing each line for each number in the range?

Tags: python, range

I'm trying to use range() to create a numbered list 1-6 and instead the program is
printing each line six times, 1 for each number

```
def main():
    file_students = open("student_points.txt", "r")
    stu_name = file_students.readline()  

    num_stu = 0
    stu_points = 0
    stu_name = 0

    print(f"Student              Points    Grade")
    print("-------------------------------------\n")
    while stu_name != "":
        stu_name = stu_name.rstrip("\n")        
        stu_points = file_students.readline()  
        stu_points = int(stu_points)
        for x in range(1):                   
            if stu_points < 60:
                print(x, f"{stu_name:15}        {stu_points} F")
            if stu_points > 60:
                print(x, f"{stu_name:15}        {stu_points}")
        num_stu += 1
        stu_name = file_students.readline()
        student_fail = num_stu < 60
    file_students.close()
    print()
    print(f"Number of students processed = {num_stu}")
    print(f"Percentage of students passing = 66%")
    print(f"Number of students failing =", student_fail)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The file that is being read contains:

```
Johnson Smith
93
Maryanne James
80
Stanton Chase
45
Mildred Morris
90
George Deitz
58
Maisie Kling
79
```

So much thanks to anyone who can help, obviously I have no idea what I'm doing

Comment: You don't need the range loop, just put a counter before the while loop.

Comment: Your code has an error (`stu_name = 0` isn't supposed to be there), but with that removed, it runs exactly as expected - your problem can't be reproduced, either you're running a different version of the script, or there is some issue with the environment you're running it in.

Comment: What is the actual output you are getting and what output do you expect to get?

Comment: for x in range(1):  will always result in x being 0

Answer (score 0):

You should use `end=''` if you don't want to go to next line.

Eg.

```
print('Hello' , end=' ')
print('World')
```

Output:
`Hello World`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to modify your code. Please have a look at my version:

```
def main():
    file_students = open("student_points.txt", "r")
    num_stu = 0         # total number of students participated
    num_fails = 0       # total number of students failed
    num_passed = 0      # total number of students passed

    print(f"Student              Points    Grade")
    print("-------------------------------------\n")

    stu_name = file_students.readline()
    while stu_name != "":
        stu_name = stu_name.rstrip("\n")
        stu_points = file_students.readline()
        stu_points = int(stu_points)
        num_stu += 1
        if stu_points < 60:
            print(num_stu, f"{stu_name:15}        {stu_points}       {'F'}")
            num_fails += 1
        if stu_points > 60:
            print(num_stu, f"{stu_name:15}        {stu_points}       {'P'}")
            num_passed += 1
        stu_name = file_students.readline()
    file_students.close()

    print()
    print(f"Number of students processed = {num_stu}")
    print(f"Percentage of students passing =", 100 * num_passed / (num_passed + num_fails))
    print(f"Number of students failing =", num_fails)
    print(f"Number of students passing =", num_passed)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and the output becomes:

```
Student              Points    Grade
-------------------------------------

1 Johnson Smith          93       P
2 Maryanne James         80       P
3 Stanton Chase          45       F
4 Mildred Morris         90       P
5 George Deitz           58       F
6 Maisie Kling           79       P

Number of students processed = 6
Percentage of students passing = 66.66666666666667
Number of students failing = 2
Number of students passing = 4
```

Comment: Thank you so so much. I have been stuck on this for days.

Comment: You are welcome! In case you want me to clarify something, let me know!